# SOAP Message encryption in Webservices

Tags: encryption, soap, websphere, ws-security

I would like to know how message confidentiality is achieved for SOAP messages.
My project uses IBM Websphere.In SOAP messages exchanged, there is

```
<wsse:KeyIdentifier>xxxx</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
```

It also has:

```
<EncryptionMethod Algorithm="yyyy"></EncryptionMethod>
<CipherData>
      <CipherValue>zzzzzzzzzzz</CipherValue>
</CipherData>
```

My doubt is whether can't a third party decrypt the *cipher text* using the *Key* ?

If not how the receiver of this message is able to decrypt the message with the information available in the SOAP message?

Or is there any initial exchange of certificates required for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to first set up a PKI infrastructure for this. The key identifier is just that, an identifier to select some private key from your key store - it is certainly not the key itself.

Please make sure handle the contents of that field in a secure fashion, since an attacker may change the value as well. My own implementation silently ignores the field since the key has been set in advance.

Comment: Be very carefull when using XML-encryption; it is well known to be vulnerable against padding oracle attacks. 

At least include XML signature in the mix, and do not allow the attacker to completely remove a signature. The attacker may also simply sign something completely different than the SOAP message itself and try to get away with that. *Always* check the signature before performing the XML decryption otherwise you will allow padding oracle attacks for sure.